# conda environment not reading dependencies

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, anaconda, conda

I created a python2.7 environment (called py27) via conda and installed two relevant modules: beautifulsoup and requests

I see that requests was installed as a dependency to my virtual env

When I was messing around with the env, I also installed beautifulsoup via pip. Confirmed this when I ran

```
conda list -n py27
```

However, when I try to run my script importing requests, it does not detect any of my installed modules

I suspect that when I run "python", it is not running python from my virtual environment, but the global environment (where I have 2.5 installed)

Is there anyway I can run this script from conda's virtual environment? Or do I need to change the ~PATH to default to whatever path my virtual environment is in?

Would it be a better idea to install these dependencies globally and just upgrade from 2.5 to 2.7?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted. Feedback on how I can improve this would be appreciated

Comment: Upvoted just because someone downvoted w/o explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out when you install a lot into the terminal, restarting it...as per usual...fixes a lot of errors.

Python versions are switching with conda and scripts are running as they are supposed to

Haha...ha...ha.